# Pandas: Comparing multiple columns to merge dataframes

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes much larger than this, but they are in the form:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c'],
                   'start': [1, 5, 10, 15],
                   'end': [4, 9, 14, 19]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c'],
                   'value': [2, 6, 12, 20],
                  'etc': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
```

I want to merge them based on checking two things in this order: 1) that `col1` matches, 2) that `value` is between `start` and `end`. I was thinking something like (but the first `==` line doesn't work):

```
if df1.col1 == df2.col1:
    if df1.start < df2.value < df1.end:
        df1.merge(df2)
```

I don't know if that will check all lines in df1 against all lines in df2 though? The desired output for this example would be:

```
dfoutput = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a', 'b', 'b'],
                        'start': [1, 5, 10],
                        'end': [4, 9, 14],
                        'value': [2, 6, 12],
                        'etc': [1, 2, 3]})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can first merge and check for value,

```
new_df = df1.merge(df2)
new_df.where(new_df.value.between(new_df.start, new_df.end)).dropna()


    col1    start   end     value   etc
0   a       1.0     4.0     2.0     1.0
1   b       5.0     9.0     6.0     2.0
4   b       10.0    14.0    12.0    3.0
5   c       15.0    19.0    16.0    4.0
```

Comment: This is actually much better, a cross join is not required.